# Find all functions from finite group $G$

Tags: finite-groups, contest-math

my task is following:

> Let be $G$ group, $|G|=n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $e\in G$ the identity element. Find all functions $f:G\to\mathbb{N}$ such that
>
> - $f(x)=1\ \Leftrightarrow\ x=e,$
> - $f\left(x^k\right)=\dfrac{f(x)}{\gcd\bigl(f(x),k\bigr)}$ for all positive divisors $k$ of $n$.

(Note that $0\notin\mathbb{N}$.)

My approach:
let be $p\mid n,$ $p$ prime and $x\in G$ of order $p$, then
$$1=f(e)=f\left(x^p\right)=\frac{f(x)}{\gcd(f(x),p)}\ \Rightarrow\ f(x)=\gcd(f(x),p)\in\{1,p\},$$
and since $f(x)=1\Leftrightarrow x=e,$ we get $f(x)=p$.

Now let be $r\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p\mid r,r\mid n,$ thus $r=lp$ for some integer $l$, and $x\in G$ of order $r$, then $$1=f(e)=f\left(x^r\right)=f\left(\left(x^l\right)^p\right)=\frac{f\left(x^l\right)}{\gcd\left(f\left(x^l\right),p\right)}$$ and again $f\left(x^l\right)=p.$

Is that enough to say that the only function fulfilling conditions is $f:x\mapsto\text{"order of }x\text{ in }G"$?

Thx.

Comment: The argument is not complete, no. In particular, you need to get to the part where you have $f(x)=r$, where $r$ is the order of $x$. You're almost there, though. You must apply the second condition again. Then it will follow that p divides f(x) to a power exactly 1 higher than p divides l, and from there it's a cakewalk.

Comment: @BenG. so I have $p=f(x^l)=f(x)/\gcd(f(x),l)$ thus $f(x)=p\gcd(f(x),l)\Rightarrow p\mid f(x)$. But what do you mean by "p divides f(x) to a power exactly 1 higher than p divides l"?

Comment: I mean that the highest power of $p$ that divides $f(x)$ is exactly one greater than the highest power of $p$ that divides $l$. The same is easily shown of $r$. In other words, when writing $f(x) = p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}$ as a product of prime powers a la the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, the primes and exponents that appear in $f(x)$'s decomposition are exactly those that appear in $r$'s. It follows that the two numbers are the same.

Comment: @BenG. Maybe I should an assumption $p\nmid l$, so as above for $r=lp$ I have $f\left(x^l\right)=p$.

Now let be $r=lp^2, p\nmid l$ and $x$ of that order, then $$p=f\left(x^{lp}\right)=f\left(\left(x^l\right)^p\right)=\frac{f\left(x^l\right)}{\gcd\left(f\left(x^l\right),p\right)}\Rightarrow f\left(x^l\right)=p^2.$$

By induction for $x,\text{ord}_G(x)=lp^m$: $f\left(x^l\right)=p^m$.

Now write $l=q_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots q_s^{\alpha_s},$ then by previous $f(x)=p^m\cdot q_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots q_s^{\alpha_s}=p^ml=\text{ord}_G(x).$

Right? :)